# Having your name added to a research paper

Tags: authorship

If I conduct experiments including behavioral tests and laboratory tests and I analyse data. I also proof-read and help writing said research paper that later goes on to get published. Is it unreasonable for me to assume that I should I be an author?

Comment: Just to make things clear, is "someone" you?

Comment: Yes and to clarify I was not considering being put down as a co author but just having my name added. There was a presentation that was done at an international conference and my name was on that abstract but the papers related to that abstract which did get published did not have my name on it.

Comment: "*I was not considering being put down as a co author but just having my name added.*"  Added as what?  As an author of the paper?  Wouldn't that make you a co-author?

Answer (score 2):

It's always unreasonable to assume someone else is going to do something that you've never discussed. Talk about authorship early on in this process! From your description it does look like they probably should have added you as an author, and it might not be too late, but you're going to have to actually talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

Authorship, if that is what you are asking about, normally requires that you have intellectual contributions to a paper, not just work and effort. If you did all of those things under the close supervision of others, then you should be acknowledged somewhere, but perhaps not as a co-author. On the other hand, if you were the instigator of some of those, or if you otherwise contributed to the *direction* of the paper, then you might be due authorship.

But such questions are subtle, and, as [Noah Snyder](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/187045/75368) says, this should have been worked out early on in the research process.

There are various lists of what is required for authorship. For example, see this one from [Harvard University](https://research.fas.harvard.edu/links/guidelines-authorship-and-acknowledgement) and note that AND is used for the individual criteria.